# finding whats wrong with my code,solving a easy competitive problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

QN;Here is the question.i dont know where my algorithm is wrong.help me find pls

Given an array A of N length. We need to calculate the next greater element for each element in given array. If next greater element is not available in given array then we need to fill ‘_’ at that index place.

Input:
The first line contains an integer T, the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains an integer n, the size of the array. Next line contains n space separated integers denoting the elements of the array.

Output:
For each test case, the output is an array that displays next greater element to element at that index.

```
Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 100
-106 <= Ai <= 106

Example:
Input
2
9
6 3 9 8 10 2 1 15 7
4
13 6 7 12

Output:
7 6 10 9 15 3 2 _ 8
_ 7 12 13
```

Explanation:
Testcase 1: Here every element of the array has next greater element but at index 7, 15 is the greatest element of given array and no other element is greater from 15 so at the index of 15 we fill with '*'.
Testcase 2: Here, at index 0, 13 is the greatest value in given array and no other array element is greater from 13 so at index 0 we fill '*'.

My solution:

```
//NOT SOLVED YET
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10]={6 ,3 ,9, 8 ,10, 2 ,1, 15, 7};
    int b[10],flag=0,big=-1,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)continue;
            if((a[j]>a[i]) && (flag==0))
            {
                big=a[j];
                flag=1;
            }
            else if(a[j]<big && big>a[i] && flag==1)
                big=a[j];

        }
        if(big==-1)cout<<'_';
        else cout<<big<<' ';
        big=-1;
        flag=0;
    }

}
```

the output i get is:

```
 2 2 2 2 7 1 0 _ 2 1
```

Comment: Here you each time "scan" over the entire list. This makes it *O(n^2)*, so I'm not sure that this meets the required efficiency.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::set`? If not, you will not be able to implement the correct solution. The correct solution using `std::set` should be only five-six lines of code.

Comment: And if you don't know `std::set`, know your data structures.  A `stack` is how you would solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
    else if(a[j] < big && a[j] > a[i] && flag == 1)
```

Indeed, if you use `big > a[i]`, then that means you just check if the *thus* far next greater element was larger than `a[i]`, but this thus makes it possible to select a value later in the process that is smaller than `big`, but smaller than `a[i]` as well. Here we thus want to check if `a[j]` is between `a[i]` and `big`.

That being said, the above approach is not very efficient. Indeed, for each element, you calculate the next element in *linear* time, making this a *quadratic* time algorithm. You might want to look at solutions where the list is sorted first. You can for example use *min-heap* here to move over the list in two passes.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what others have mentioned - that you currently have an O(N^2) algorithm, and this can be done more efficiently.

I don't think you can get O(N) here, but here is a plan for an O(N log N) algorithm:

For each test case:

- Load the Ai values into two arrays, let's call them X and Y
- Sort the Y array
- Iterate over X and for each element of X do a binary search into Y to find the next larger value of Ai: use that as the output, or use _ if you did not find one

I recommend, for practice purposes, implementing this both using the C++ standard library, using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound , and implementing the above two functions yourself, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: I am kinda new to algorithms,than you for ur recommendations